# Including external css files in Famo.us project

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, famo.us

I've created a project using Famo.us's Yeoman generator. It creates an index.html file, a styles folder, a src folder, and a content folder. The gruntfile specifies that index.html includes all css files under the styles folder. However, I want to include a google fonts css file, by referencing it in my index.html. I can't insert this manually because grunt will overwrite my changes everytime i save a file in my project, how do I go about making grunt load my external css files/reference them in my index.html file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include your stylesheet **outside** of the `<!-- build:css` comments.

This works:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/famous/core/famous.css" />

<!-- build:css(app/) css/app.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/app.css" />
<!-- bower:css -->
```

#### Troubleshooting:

- If this does not work with live-reload, try restarting the server!
- Be sure to refresh page (i.e. clear cache or open developer console)

#### Example files:

See [example files in this gist](https://gist.github.com/markmarijnissen/10578387)!

#### Explanation:

The specific Grunt task that rewrites CSS stylesheets in index.html is called `cssmin`, which is used in conjunction with `useminPrepare` and `usemin`.

Basically, `useminPrepare` writes a `cssmin` configration for you based on the `<!-- build:css` comments in your html file. See [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) docs.